# Assigning groupid across shared common columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.frame (in reality it's millions of records).

I'd like to be able to assign a `group_id` when a phone number matches across any other record and any phone number position.

```
id <- c(1:5)
phone_1 <- c("444","", "333", "222", "")
phone_2 <- c("", "444", "111", "", "")
phone_3 <- c("222","", "", "", "111")
df <- data.frame(id, phone_1, phone_2, phone_3)
```

The output would be:

```
print(df)
#   id phone_1 phone_2 phone_3  group_id
# 1  1     444             222  1
# 2  2             444          1
# 3  3     333     111          2
# 4  4     222                  1
# 5  5                     111  2
```

Note that missing values (`""` or `NA`) should be treated as incomparables (or all of the above would be in the same group).

Comment: What if the second record looks like this: `id=2`, `phone_1=""`, `phone_2="444"`, `phone_3="111"`; would it have a group `ID` of `1` or `2`?

Comment: @TeeKea It would result in 1 group ID across the entire example as numbers link all records (by degrees of separation).

Record 1 links to record 2 (444), record 1 links to record 4 (222), Record 2 (111) links to record 3 and 5, and to tie them together, record 1 links to record 4 (222)

Comment: Is each value an actual 7 or 10 digit phone number?

Comment: @Michael 10 digit character (in Australia where state prefix starts with 0). Out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: In USA it is common to break down phone numbers into chunks like XXX XXX XXXX so I wasn't sure if you had three separate 10 digit phone numbers, or three chunks of numbers that together make a phone number. It was more curiosity. Furthermore, the latter scenario would have far more matches which actually means fewer groups. The distinction could theoretically change my approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution finding components of a graph:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

df$id <- paste0("id-", df$id)

graph <- 
  df %>%
  gather(dummy, phone, -id) %>% 
  select(-dummy) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(phone) & phone != "") %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  graph_from_edgelist(directed = FALSE)

plot(graph)
```

[image]

```
df$ID <- components(graph)$membership[df$id]

df

#     id phone_1 phone_2 phone_3 ID
# 1 id-1     444             222  1
# 2 id-2             444          1
# 3 id-3     333     111          2
# 4 id-4     222                  1
# 5 id-5                     111  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `@Aurèle` solution, if you want to compute it with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

dt <- data.table(id, phone_1, phone_2, phone_3)
graph <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(melt(dt, "id", names(dt)[grepl("phone", names(dt))])
                                       [!is.na(value) & value != ""][, variable := NULL]),
                             directed = FALSE)

dt[, ID := components(graph)$membership[dt[, as.character(id)]]]

#    id phone_1 phone_2 phone_3 ID
# 1:  1     444             222  1
# 2:  2             444          1
# 3:  3     333     111          2
# 4:  4     222                  1
# 5:  5                     111  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the data.table method. The compute time is from the igraph function, so I feel @Auréle's solution was first. This answer is missing the `df$id <- paste0("id-", df$id)` step as well.